# GWT PopupPanel with Buttons

Tags: java, css, gwt, smartgwt

I have a class that extends the smartgwt ImgButton. When the Button is pressed a popup should be shown that contains further buttons. The buttons in this popup should not be rendered like common buttons, but rather like text links - so I applied a custom CSS class. Everything works fine so far. But when I press any of the buttons in the popup, the background of the button gets transparent and the text behind the popup shines through. This is ugly, but I can't find a way to solve this.

Does anyone have an idea how to keep the background color when the button is pressed?

Here is the code:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.smartgwt.client.types.Alignment;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.ImgButton;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Button;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickHandler;

public class MultiButton extends ImgButton {

    private PopupPanel popup;
    private VerticalPanel content;

    public MultiButton() {
        super();
        popup = new PopupPanel();
        popup.setAnimationEnabled(true);
        popup.setAutoHideEnabled(true);

        content = new VerticalPanel();
        popup.add(content);

        this.setWidth(18);
        this.setHeight(18);
        this.setShowRollOver(false);
        this.setShowDown(false);
        this.setSrc("person.png");
        this.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
                popup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                        int left = event.getX() + 7;
                        int top = event.getY() + 7;

                        popup.setPopupPosition(left, top);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void addMultiButtonEntry(String name, ClickHandler handler) {        
        Button b = new Button(popup.getStyleName());
        b.addClickHandler(handler);

        b.setShowHover(false);
        b.setShowRollOver(false);

        b.setBaseStyle("nt-multibutton-button");

        b.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);

        content.add(b);
    }
}
```

and this is the CSS definition:

```
.nt-multibutton-button {
    border: 0px !important;
    color: #657380;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width:90%;
    background-color: white;    
}
```

Thank you for every hint!

PS: I know it isn't good style to mix SmartGWT and GWT components, but I didn't find a PopUp in SmartGWT and I don't want to code my own.

Comment: You should use Firebug to know which style is responsible for this transparency and try to override this in your CSS. It might work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out how to do it.

I added a style primary name and the style name to the buttons and now it works :)

So the buttons for the popup are now created as follows:

```
    Button b = new Button(name);
    b.addClickHandler(handler);

    b.setShowHover(false);
    b.setShowRollOver(false);

    String css = "nt-multibutton-button";
    b.setStylePrimaryName(css);
    b.setBaseStyle(css);
    b.setStyleName(css);

    b.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);

    content.add(b);
```